# Calabash - do not reinstall app on startup

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-testing, calabash, calabash-android

My app on the first run the user has to authenticate.

I've a feature with different tagged scenarios. Now I need to run just a few scenarios but every time I run the following command

```
calabash-android run /path/to/apk features/my.feature --tags @Alert
```

My app is reinstalled which causes the tests to fail on my @Alert scenario. How can I tell calabash to not reinstall the app?

From googling around I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-android/Ql3iluRMijg) which says:

```
Go to app_installation_hooks.rb file under support folder and comment out following 3 lines:

uninstall_apps
install_app(......)
install_app(......)
```

but I'm looking for a command or more elegant way to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update your app_installation_hooks and add a tagged Before hook.

The Calabash iOS Smoke Test [01_launch.rb](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/features/support/01_launch.rb) (yes, it is an iOS example, but the principles are the same) has examples of what I mean.

```
Before('@reset_app_btw_scenarios') do
  if xamarin_test_cloud?
    ENV['RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS'] = '1'
  elsif LaunchControl.target_is_simulator?
    target = LaunchControl.target
    simulator = RunLoop::Device.device_with_identifier(target)
    app = RunLoop::App.new(ENV['APP'])
    core_sim = RunLoop::CoreSimulator.new(simulator, app)
    core_sim.reset_app_sandbox
  else
    LaunchControl.install_on_physical_device
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber provides a number of [hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) which allow us to run blocks at various points in the Cucumber test cycle.

I think what you need is the **Tagged hooks**

Sometimes you may want a certain hook to run only for certain scenarios. This can be achieved by associating a Before, After, Around or AfterStep hook with one or more tags.